# How to use "innuendo" in a sentence

Tags: innuendo

The word "Innuendo" is rarely used in articles and books. It is usually just found in informal conversations. I was wondering which phrasing seems correct, as well as which may be the best wording.

1."The singer’s comments were innuendoes that referred to love-making."

2."The singer’s comments were innuendoes about love-making."

3."The singer’s comments were innuendoes, which alluded to love-making."

*4. "The singer’s comments were innuendoes that alluded to love-making."

Comment: Your premise is false; *innuendo* is found more often in writing than in speech.

Comment: I googled to find such articles or books before posting. The books seem kind of untrustworthy. I was hoping to find some article from a highly reputable news source, but I mostly found sources that I wouldn't trust completely.

Comment: @LedZepp You can use Google Books instead of the normal search to find higher-quality sources. Or use a more traction all corpus, like the COCA Corpus. Having said that, using *innuendo* as you are strikes my ear wrong.

Comment: Finding the answer is not as easy as it may seem. I have spent the past 20 minutes looking at https://filosofie101.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/bell_innuendo_1997.pdf and you would be surprised how often the author clearly structured the sentences to avoid phrasing the sentences in any way like I did. Perhaps because that is the correct way to write it. But I have been looking on Google Scholar, and all of the writers seem to do that too. But there has to be a more efficient way to mention that someone used an innuendo, while also showing what the innuendo was actually about.

Comment: @LedZepp Innuendo is, by default, about sex: there is no need to specify that. And I don't think "finding the answer isn't as easy as it seems" is true. In fact, I think you already found the answer. People do not structure sentences using *innunedo* the way you are trying to. It's not that they're going out of their way to avoid your structuring, it's that your structuring is built on a false belief about how the word is or can be used. We do not say "her words were innuendo", for the same reason we don't say "her words were saying". It's redundant. An innuendo presumes words have been said.

Comment: That is a very good point. But I am actually writing something else though, so I used a salient and simplified example to base my question on. I should have stated that earlier, I'm sorry. I am starting to think number 3 is the best answer though. Do you agree? Except maybe it should be phrased as "The singer’s comments were innuendoes that alluded to love-making."

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to phrase the following idea: "The singer's words were innuendo that alluded to baseball." Is that a correct way to phrase it, to get across not only that innuendo was used but what it was actually referencing?

Comment: @DanBron COCA is virtually useless as a corpus of English speech; most of what it designates as "spoken" is transcripts of television newscasts, and it makes no distinction between scripted recitations, formal interviews with practised politicians and academics, whose speech typically emulates the written dialect more or less successfully, and actual spontaneous interviews--and even the last are edited to intelligible soundbytes.

Comment: Can you give more context for your statement? None of your suggestions work for me; that's just not how the word is used. But there likely *is* a way to make the point you're trying to make, if we know precisely what it is.

Comment: Well this is the reason I asked the question. How does a person say that a comment was innuendo, and also say what the innuendo was? As an analogy, think of this sentence: "She said that the suspect was still at large, but her insinuation was that I was probably the culprit." That would probably be fine as a sentence. But how does one specifically mention innuendo, and what it was alluding to? Succinctness is also a concern, which is why I want to find a way to write it in a single sentence.

Comment: @DanBron, I don't think that innuendo necessarily has to be about sex. You could make an innuendo about non-sexual bodily functions, for example.

Comment: @vanderpn I agree innuendo does not have to be about sex, but it is by default, and will be taken that way unless otherwise specified. In other words: saying *innuendo about sex* is pleonastic.

Comment: @DanBron Innuendo has to be denigrating, but I'm unconvinced that without modification it will be taken to refer to sex. The Ngram viewer reports that currently the most popular word immediately preceding *innuendo* is *sexual*, which would seems high if it's the default. Sexual connotation is not part of the word's meaning in defamation law.

Comment: @deadrat Quite right. *Innuendo* can apply to any suggested wrongdoing, or practice which the other party would prefer to keep hidden. It is straightforward Latin, from the verb *innuere*, meaning *to nod to*, or *signify*. The most common way I would use it would be to say something like: *they stand accused **by innuendo** of accepting bribes*. Speaking *by innuendo* is in itself seen as less than frank or forthright, as a way of casting aspersions about people without actually saying as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example: Pamela asked where Jacob spent the night.  Her innuendo was that he was cheating on her. I think it is the French word that means implication or insinuation.

from The Online Etymology Dictionary ..

innuendo (n.) 
"oblique hint, indiscreet suggestion," usually a deprecatory one, 1670s, from Latin innuendo "by meaning, pointing to," literally "giving a nod to," ablative of gerund of innuere "to mean, signify," literally "to nod to," from in- "at" (see in- (2)) + nuere "to nod" (see numinous).

Originally in English a legal phrase (1560s) from Medieval Latin, with the sense of "to wit," introducing an explanatory or parenthetical clause, it also introduced the derogatory meaning alleged in libel cases, which led to broader meaning. As a verb,from 1706.

Innuendo is not necessarily about sex, but usually has pejorative connotation.

from http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Sexual+innuendo :

innuendo (redirected from Sexual innuendo)

n. from Latin innuere, "to nod toward." In law it means "an indirect hint." "Innuendo" is used in lawsuits for defamation (libel or slander), usually to show that the party suing was the person about whom the nasty statements were made or why the comments were defamatory. Example: "the former Mayor is a crook," and Joe Alabaster is the only living ex-Mayor, thus by innuendo Alabaster is the target of the statement; or "Joe Alabaster was paid $100,000 by the Hot Springs Water Company," when it was known that Hot Springs was bucking for a contract with the city. **The innuendo is that Alabaster took a bribe.**

Comment: Did you make up that example, or do you have a source for it? I have never heard *innuendo* used that way, and would expect one of the other two words you mention in that sentence. Also, I think you meant to take out the last sentence of your first paragraph, as it is directly contradicted by your edit.

Comment: I "made up" that example, but that is one way I have used it, unchallenged, for a half  century as a native speaker of American English.  For other examples, see http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/innuendo . The root of the word is Latin,  the first recorded use in English is 1560's.  There is no contradiction.  I don't really know French well enough to know if they still use the word, but Google translates the word innuendo from French to English unchanged.

Comment: P.S. The examples provided by the original poster were gramatically correct, but they were meta-language, i.e. descriptive of language use, rather than characteristically normal usage of the word.

Comment: None of those examples match yours or the OP's. The closest is "He offered an innuendo about the drinking problem."
http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/innuendo#FzUOmOcgWHgGwzJ4.99

Comment: The second example I had was probably too ambiguous though. Because people may wonder whether the "about" is referring to the ostensible topic, or the surreptitious topic. I think that using a word like "alluded" or "referenced" may help the reader discern the surreptitious topic immediately, without have to know context in order to infer that the "about" meant the surreptitious topic and not the ostensible topic.

Comment: Another example, this one from https://mobile.twitter.com/albertabeef/status/727168205358137349 "The innuendo is that we don't raise our beef, our cattle, humanely, which is absolutely wrong," attribution: Bob Lowe, ABP Chair

Comment: This construct, i.e. "the innuendo is that ..." is in fact a de-construction or analysis, ostensibly exposing the unstated implication of the innuendo.

Comment: We don't need to say "The innuendo of the innuendo is that ..."